# Programming Error syncing Postgres with Oscar in Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, postgresql-9.1, django-oscar

I'm following the OSCAR tutorial (http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html) and am trying to get Haystack to work with Solr.  I've set up postgres.  I'm running on Cloud9.  I try to run "$ python manage.py syncdb --noinput"  This ends up killed when Running migrations...

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/utils/__init__.py:12: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils import importlib

/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py:20: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
  from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericForeignKey

/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py:24: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9
  warnings.warn("The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: reports_dashboard, offers_dashboard, treebeard, communications_dashboard, reviews_dashboard, pages_dashboard, shipping_dashboard, haystack, promotions_dashboard, checkout, thumbnail, vouchers_dashboard, django_tables2, partners_dashboard, staticfiles, oscar, compressor, catalogue_dashboard, users_dashboard, search, messages, widget_tweaks, dashboard, ranges_dashboard, orders_dashboard
  Apply all migrations: customer, promotions, shipping, wishlists, offer, admin, sessions, contenttypes, auth, payment, reviews, analytics, catalogue, flatpages, sites, address, basket, partner, order, voucher
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table thumbnail_kvstore
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...Killed
```

I've also tried to run this without --noinput

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/utils/__init__.py:12: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils import importlib

/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py:20: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
  from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericForeignKey

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 182, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "oscar_vagrant" does not exist
```

If I try to runserver it states the DB isn't synced... when I try to load the page I get this...

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "promotions_pagepromotion" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "promotion...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://love-benbuehne.c9.io/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "promotions_pagepromotion" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "promotion...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 64
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/workspace',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace',
 '/home/ubuntu/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/oscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 10 Jul 2015 22:54:01 +0000
```

I'm kind of befuddled as to what this means.  It seems as if I have an issue syncing the database... and it seems as if there is just some sort of error that is just beyond me.  I'm not even sure what files I could copy to here that would be helpful.  Best I can tell Django is accessing postgres... and for some strange reason it isn't syncing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop your database, delete your migrations and then run syncdb or makemigrations whatever you want. may be this will help. 
 If it does not work then please show me your models file.

Comment: It worked... I dropped the database and re-created it.  I also noted that somehow an SQlite file had been created somehow and deleted this.  When I ran syncdb again it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly because, in oscar I guess you have added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [] + get_core_apps(['app.promotions'])
```

Where `app` is your application. As home page of oscar is written in promotions. The models of the platform aren't included. You can solve that by using importing the component in the `__init__.py` except what you require.

`app/promotions/__init__.py` should contain `from oscar.apps.promotions import *`